# Single stepping between events in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Using Visual Studio 2010 Premium. Is there any way in the debugger to single step between events which fire in an ASP.NET page life cycle? So for example after Page_Load ends, I would like to single step into the next event or at least know was was the next event which fired during debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with little success as some of the early events have not loaded any page data. You can access them by overriding them in the aspx page. Within your code behind type `public override` and intellisense will popup with all the page's events that you can override amongst other methods. Try to stick to the basic one's.

This link contains the asp.net page life cyle's most general steps. It may help you out.

[ASP.NET Page life cycle on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not practical as it involves too much code change. I have to know what they are first to override them. I am looking for a more straight forward way.